# Connection.query() return the rows undefined

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have a method getconnection() that creates connection for me.
 Here's the function.

I get undefined even if I am fetching result of query that is rows to callback function to send the response to controller.
Can someone help me out.Thanks in advance.

```
function fetchUserInfo(req,res)
{
   var getUserInfo = "select First_Name, Last_Name,COUNT(*) FROM     twitter.user_information INNER join twitter.tweets ON user_information.Twitter_Handle = tweets.Twitter_handle WHERE user_information.Twitter_Handle = '"+req.session.handle+"' ";
console.log("Fetch User-------------"+getUserInfo);
    mysql.fetchUser(function(err,result){

    if(err)
    {   console.log("cannot be retrieved");
        throw err;
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("Successfully retrieved");
        console.log("---------------" + result);
        console.log(result.First_Name);
        res.send(result);
    }
},getUserInfo);
```

}

// mysql function

function fetchUser(callback,sqlQuery)
{

```
console.log("In fetch Data");
console.log("SQLquery is:::"+sqlQuery);
connection.getConnection().query(sqlQuery, function(err,rows,fields){

    if(err)
    {
        console.log("Error :"+err.message);

    }
    else
    {
        console.log("Result is :" + rows.First_Name);
        callback(err, rows);
    }
})
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
console.log("Result is :" + rows[0].First_Name);
```

or try to print the rows variable to the console instead of rows.First_Name:

```
console.log(rows);
```